# Error running docker container: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to dockerize a simple Python-Flask application but I am getting an error while running my container.

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Workdir on localhost:

```
/home/ubuntu/flask_web
- app.py
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
```

app.py

```
#flask_web/app.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hey, we have Flask in a Docker container'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER xyz "xyz@gmail.com"

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common vim \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Commands:

```
docker build -t flask-test:latest .
docker run -p 5000:5000 flask-test
```

Expected : Flask web should run on port 5000

Actual Result:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Comment: Could it be that you need to run `python3` instead?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no `/usr/bin/python` in a docker image built by the code above. But there is `/usr/bin/python3`. So you could either use `python3` directly  as your `ENTRYPOINT` or create a symlink.

Comment: I changed my entry point to python3 but now I'm getting a invalid syntax error in From flask import Flask on running the container. My requirements.txt do contain 
flask==0.10.1

so I don't know why flask library is not binding with the python.

Comment: Oh its just a simple syntax error thanks it's resolved now.

Comment: My Dockerfile and ENTRYPOINTS are like in the post somewhat, and had a similar issue that got resolved by changing the ENTRYPOINT to "python3". But upon running the docker - 'docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-sample', a large string is return '98d3b5.....' and the command exits, upon checking with 'docker ps -a', the status is shown 'Excited' although it should be running on port 5000, ideally. What am I missing, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same issue except that it was yelling some other number than 344

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.` 
and the docker file was

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

I changed the line
`ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]` 
to `ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]` 
Now it is working fine.
The reason for this was that above I had used Python3 so there was no candidate for Python rather there were for Python3.

```
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error when building a flask app docker image. I fixed it by installing:

`RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers`

If you are using **alpine**, use the above command. Otherwise use apt-get or other commands to install these libraries

Comment: musl-dev?? what does that do?

Comment: just in case flask has some dependencies which need c lib

Comment: it is suitable for alpine without python